# __config_site: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm trying to build my project with CMake on WSL 2 with Ubuntu, using g++11.3 (but I can see that compiler version isn't the problem here). There are several compilation errors in various source files:

```
/usr/local/include/__config:13:10: fatal error: __config_site: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <__config_site>
      |
```

I found that file `__config_site.in` exists, but somehow is not visible for the compiler. I totally don't have any idea what can be the root cause here. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
The error occurs also in such minimal example:
main.cpp

```
#include <algorithm> // e.g. this header makes error

int main() {

}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
```

Full error stacktrace:
in this case:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdlib.h:87,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:62,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/__config:13:10: fatal error: __config_site: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <__config_site>
      |
```

Comment: What's `/usr/local/include/__config`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I updated with MRE

Comment: Whatever `/usr/local/include/stdlib.h` is seems to be conflicting with the compilers standard library

Answer (score 0):

Basically what worked for me:

```bash
cp -avp \
  $(find /opt/git/llvm-project/build -iname "*__config_site*") \
  /opt/local/include/c++/v1/
```

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 18.1.0rc (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 6d8f9290b6afa5e61841124ae1bdeb96d9ada820)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/local/bin
```

And compile this way:

```bash
clang++ \
  -std=c++20 \
  -nostdinc++ -nostdlib++ \
  -isystem /opt/local/include/c++/v1/ \
  -L /opt/local/lib/ \
  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/ \
  -lc++ -lfmt -pthread \
  -o /tmp/main.run /tmp/main.cc
```

Obviously, if you have installed clang somewhere else than `/opt/local/`, then adjust you paths. (I've heard rumours that it might work even from the withing the `build`-directory...)

Comment: You use clang and OP uses g++. For clang this is a known issue for 1.5Y+ : https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/57104